# How to select value in DatagridviewComboboxColumn Cell

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview which contain a Combobox Column i want when i select a add value from the combobox it shows a new form. i tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
private void dataGridView2_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (dataGridView2.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name)
            {
                case "CategorieDataGridViewTextBoxColumn":

                    if (dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["CategorieDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value.ToString() == "Add")
                    {
                        Categorie cat = new Categorie();
                        cat.Show();

                    }

                    break;
            }

        }
```

So how can i do it??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should handle the event when a value is changed in a ComboBox in a DataGridView cell. try this code which will fire the event of the selection in the comboBox in the dataGridView:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmbcolumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        dataGridView2.EditingControlShowing += new DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventHandler(dataGridView2_EditingControlShowing);


    }

    private void dataGridView2_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox combo = e.Control as ComboBox;
        if (combo != null)
        {
            combo.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
            combo.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
        }
    }

    private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)sender;
        string item = cb.Text;
        if (item == "Add")
        {
            Categorie cat = new Categorie();
            cat.Show();

        }
    }
```